# How do I get the submitted moderation state of a custom block?

Tags: hooks, workflows

I am a bit new for Drupal and currently working on Drupal8. I need to implement custom restrictions for workflow. Basically i want to get the submitted value of `moderation_state` filed in `mymodule_form_alte`

Here are the things that i have tried but all returns `Null`. The strange thing is that the below method works for **node** but do not work for **block_content**

```
 function mymodule_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   $formSate = $form_state->getValue('moderation_state')[0]['valye'];
   var_dump($formState); // Output : Null

   $formSate = $form['moderation_state']['widget']['#default_value'];
   var_dump($formState); // Output : return the default value of dropdown not the one that i have selected
}
```

Here is the moderation_state field 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

all most there try the following

```
// Get the current  entity.
$entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
$moderation_state = $entity->get('moderation_state')->getString();
// Do the things.
```

or 
   in a submit or validation thing 
   try to

```
// use dump() as it is way better 
dump($form_state->getValues()) // <-- and find in the array
```